# Shiny numeric field not accepting user entered number

Tags: r, shiny

The "total" field is the sum of the "A", "B" and "Everything Else" field.
The "total" field auto updates when I change any of "A", "B" or "Everything Else".
Great.

Suppose the user enters $5,000 in the "total" field.
What I would like to happen is that the "total" field accepts the 5000 and "Everything Else" = "total" - "A" - "B"

How can this be done?

Currently anything manually entered in the "total" field is ignored. If I enter 5000 in "total" and then increment "A", the 5000 from the "total" field disappears.

```
library("shiny")
library("bslib")
library("shinyWidgets")

per_month <- "/mth"

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  # https://bootswatch.com/journal/
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5, "font_scale" = 1.0), 
  div(class = "container-fluid",
      
      div(class="col-4", 
          numericInputIcon(
            inputId = "total",
            label = "Total",
            value = 0,
            min = 0,
            max = 9000,
            width = "160px",
            icon = list(NULL, per_month)
          ),
      ),
      div(class = "row",
          div(class="col-4", 
              numericInputIcon(
                inputId = "a",
                label = "A",
                value = 100,
                min = 0,
                max = 9000,
                width = "160px",
                icon = list(NULL, per_month)
              ),
          ),
          div(class="col-4", 
              numericInputIcon(
                inputId = "b",
                label = "B",
                value = 200,
                min = 0,
                max = 9000,
                width = "160px",
                icon = list(NULL, per_month)
              ),
          ),
          ), 
          div(class="col-4", 
              numericInputIcon(
                inputId = "any",
                label = "Everything Else",
                value = 50,
                min = 0,
                max = 9000,
                width = "160px",
                icon = list(NULL, per_month)
              )
          )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateNumericInputIcon(
      session = session,
      inputId = "total",
      value = input$a + input$b + input$any
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This will end in a circle relationship. Each time you update `any` with `total` -> `total` will be updated with `any` (because `any` is changed by `total`) and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `freezeReactiveValue`:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    updateNumericInputIcon(
      session = session,
      inputId = "total",
      value = input$a + input$b + input$any
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$total, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "any")
    updateNumericInputIcon(
      session = session,
      inputId = "any",
      value = input$total - (input$a + input$b)
    )
  })
  
}
```